# Websites manager or organizer

Tags: web-development, project-management, product-management

I run many *separate* local business websites.

Each one has:

- different owner
- different URL
- different usernames & passwords
- different hosting
- different domain expiration date
- different SEO problems
- different social media
- different plugins and technical solutions
- different website-specific information I need to remember about
- different to-do list

and so on.

And the number of websites I run grows. It's getting pretty hard to keep up with all this data, because I don't have one place where I have all this information. As a matter of fact I don't have problem with *running* all these websites, but I do have a problem spending an inappropiate amount of time to organize the sites’ meta-data.

Right now I use [OneNote](http://www.onenote.com/) for notes about websites, [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) for storing website-related files, [GQueues](https://www.gqueues.com/) for to-do lists and collaboration, [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar) to remember about expiration dates of hosting & domains and e-mail for contacting website owners.

I wonder if there is some software (not necessarily a free solution) that can assist me with keeping up with this - in other words, I need some kind of organizer.

I'm interested in any solution, but if there is some choice the order is (best to worst solution for me):

1. Self hosted on LAMP
2. Webapp
3. local app for Linux Debian Family
4. local app for Windows

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a tree-structured information manager, e.g.:

- [TreeDBNotes](http://www.mytreedb.com/treedbnotes_pro.html) - has big disadvantages as loading slowly and numerous bugs, but has no competition among other tree-structured PIMs in terms of flexibility and features. It has tabs along trees, allows password protection on a file level, tab level and branch level; maintains tables very well and linking between branches of coures;
- [EssentialPIM](http://www.essentialpim.com) - lightweight, yet rich in features, very user-friendly interface.

Comment: Have you used any of them? A little more info about each one would be nice...

Comment: @brasofilo - Thanks, I added some info.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Website Management](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-websites-manager) template on Simitless. It will solve your issue of having the information regarding your websites spread across different places, as you can tune the template to track your exact needs. And, as your needs change, develop and grow, you can modify the template (well, by the time it is your own web app) accordingly.

The way it works is that you get predefined spreadsheet-columns-like fields that you can select from to track/collect only the data you need.

If you can export the data regarding your websites from the current systems you are using, you can import it easily into your web app to save you time. (By the way, you can also export it at any time).

And, since it is a web app, it runs on any device with a browser, be it pc, tablet, phone, etc.

Here is a little screenshot of what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

1. Main view:
   [image]
2. View inside the record:
   [image]

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.